# is there a way to get all related data in laravel connection?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables named `posts` and `categories`. these two tables have one-to-many relationship and I wrote them in models like this:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    ...
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id', 'id');
    }
    ...
}
```

```
class Category extends Model
{

    ...
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'category_id', 'id');
    }
    ...
}
```

This is work fine when I use `$post = Post::find($id)` in controller and retrieve one post and use `$post->category` to get category of this post. but what if I want to retrieve all posts and their categories together?
I mean, let's assume that I have 10 posts in DataBase and I have `$posts = Post::get();` to get all posts. now, how I can get categories of each post?
One way is loop! for example:

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    $post['category'] = $post->category;
}

return response()->json($posts);
```

Yeah! I want to response in Json and I forgot to say earlier, sorry.

Is there better way to do this? I searched and I got nothing by my search. I'll be appreciated if anyone response to my problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to include categories in each post model with json, is simply including it using `with()` and it will automatically transform it.

```
return Post::with('category')->get();
```

In `Laravel` you do not have to wrap models or collections in `response->json();` it will automatically do that.

Comment: I'm not certain this is axcatcly what you want but else comment i expect you want the following json structure.

[{"name": "post 1", "category": {"name": "cat 1"}}]